# Get the dimension to pass to getDimensionPixelSize?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, pixel

When using getDimensionPixelSize(dimension); how do you know what is the dimension? Where can I get this value from?

Comment: It is something like `R.drawable.my_bitmap` . Read [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimensionPixelSize%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

The dimension is any dimension object which is usually defined in your dimens.xml file inside your values resource folder.

If you want to get the actual pixel size of a dimension, you can say:

```
getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.mysize);
```

This will get the actual pixel size of:

```
<dimen name="mysize">16dp</dimen>
```

For example

Comment: But what if I have an ImageView that matches parent width? How do I know that width?

Comment: You can simply say imageViewObj.getWidth() any time after the view has been inflated. This is not related to getDImensionPixelSize()

Answer (score 0):

You can get the dimension from a `dimen` resource

Assuming that you define a resource like this

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="popup_width">300dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="popup_height">250dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

You can have the pixel size with :

```
getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.popup_width);
```

Comment: Dont you mean :getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.popup_width);